# Is there a way to walk back on a CaseComment query to filter by AccountId?

Tags: apex, soql, query, case, case-comment

I don't believe this is possible other then doing a nested query but I wanted to double check with everyone in case I was missing the boat.

```
SELECT Id, CommentBody, CreatedDate, ParentId, CreatedById FROM CaseComments WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId ORDER BY ParentId, CreatedDate DESC
```

AccountId is obviously not a field on CaseComments so I can not do this. How would I walk CaseComments back to Account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
SELECT Id, CommentBody, CreatedDate, ParentId, Parent.AccountId FROM CaseComment
```

Where Parent.AccountId would give you the AccountId from the Case.

Comment: That will do a better job :)